# PyCharm misbehavior in project settings

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2020.3.5 CE on Ubuntu.

I had created a file and when asked what kind of a file I wanted to create I have specified a "Unit test" instead of "Python file".
I wanted to change this type but I did not succeed.
I deleted the file and created again a Python file with the same file name but PyCharm is still marking this file as a Unit test and I cannot Run it from PyCharm.

Is there a way to reset manually this project setting that is kept memorised somewhere?

Comment: If the file is deleted it's gone, the file extension is what matters. In case your Project configuration somehow became stale use "invalidate caches", restart the IDE, or search for the file inside the configuration files in the `.idea` folder of the project.

Comment: Hi @bad_coder, tried both but still the error persisted. It's very annoying...